# Rsync a portion of image sequences

Tags: linux, terminal, rsync

I have an image sequence as follows:

```
some_images.####.jpg   0001   1000
```

But I had only wanted to do a rsync from 0001 to 0120, by using rsync from a local to a remote server. Can this be done using rsync command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by specifying each of the 120 filenames individually:

```
rsync some_images0001.jpg some_images0002.jpg (etc..) yourhost:yourdir/
```

Knowing that, we can use bash to generate the above command with all 120 filenames automatically:

```
rsync some_images{0001..0120}.jpg yourhost:yourdir/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back. Regarding the latter solution that you have posted, I did a quick test and it is working, however I suppose it is only possible if I am writing it as `{0001,0002,0003,0004,0005...,0120}`, so there is no command such as `{0001-0120}` style?

Comment: `some_images{0001..0120}.jpg` works on bash 4.0 and later. If it doesn't work for you, maybe you are using old bash 3, where this would become `some_images1.jpg` instead of `some_images0001.jpg`? You can try it with an `echo` in front to see what exactly it generates.